# I just notice small lines on the upper right of my dell laptop. I never remembered on doing something to make this happened

Tags: dell-latitude

I just notice small lines on the upper right of my dell laptop. I never remembered on doing somthing to make this happened. What should I do to make this lines disappear? [small line about 2 inches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X816T.jpg)

Comment: It looks like the screen is damaged, nothing you can do other than replacing the display panel. Or is it only visible when logged in, and not when logged out or booting?

Comment: Do the lines persist when you change the background image? Have you tried a pixel mapping tool to (attempt to) revive dead pixels? It looks a lot like a graphics driver issue, but the above will help understand whether that is the case.